# Observable - subscribe & process only the latest available for each invocation

Tags: observable, reactive-programming, rx-py

assume you have an Observable stream of values which pushes a values very fast.

Now let's say you have a subscriber which needs to update a record in a database with the latest values from this observable stream, i.e. a somewhat slow I/O bound consumer.

In other words, imagine

```
from rx import Observable
obs = Observable.interval(1)

# Whoops. Observable will push values faster than we can consume them here.
sub = obs.subscribe( do_some_io_bound_operation )
```

Is there any way to "skip" all except for the latest values that the observable creates in between different on_next invocations?

In other words: Assume in the example above, obs starts pushing values 1,2,3...
The subscriber invokes do_some_io_bound_operation with value "1". This takes a while - by the time its done, values 2 and 3 are available. But instead of calling do_some_io_bound_operation on both new available values, the subscriber should ideally just skip value "2" and directly move on the value 3.

Bit hard to describe - I hope the intention is clear. Is there any way to achieve this?

I'd suppose .Buffer() goes into the direction - but most applications I've seen just buffer by some fixed number of elements or a timespan, whereas I'd need to buffer dynamically (buffer everything that happens while on_next is being executed)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no right way.
The Observable **notifies** the subscribed Observer instance whenever an event occurs, so the Subscriber does not have access to all items and can not affect the stream generation.
You can perform time-based operations on Observable level, [debounce for example](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html), but you cannot block/skip elements during the work on the Subscriber.
You can implement your own [custom operator](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html#custom-operator) for skipping messages but this is idiomatically wrong.